# How to send two packets in a point-to-point transmission with NOMA?

Tags: capacity, channel

If a transmitter T1 has two packets M1 and M2 to send to a receiver R1, can T1 send M1 and M2 at the same time and using the same frequency based on Non-orthogonal multiple access (NOMA)?

If T1 sends x = P1*M1 + P2*M2 with allocated power P1 and P2. Then R1 will receive y1 = x*h1 + n1 where h1 is the channel gain between T1 and R1 and n1 is the noise. Can R1 decode both M1 and M2?

Comment: yes, and yes, as covered by your previous question. Your title doesn't match the content of your question!

Comment: The question is how to decode the two messages. If we send P1*M1+P2*M2, how the receiver will detect them, or how the interference is cancelled?

Comment: No, your questions here are just "can XYZ do ABC?", not specifically what you're asking here in the comment! Please clarifiy your question by editing it, and explaining exactly what you're missing - I mean, I mentioned successive interference cancellation in my previous answer, and I feel you're kind of picking up on this, but I don't understand where you're stuck. **Edit** your question please!